# How to call activity on click parent item in expandable listview

Tags: android

In expandable list view i want to set only parent item in first position and other parent item  will have child item. what i want to do when i click on first position(parent item) it will open other activity. 
for example:- when i click home menu it will open other activity. please see screenshot [this is expandable list view in drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrAey.png)

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected Toolbar toolbar;
protected ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
SessionManager sessionManager;
protected DrawerLayout drawer;
protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
protected LinearLayout linearLayout;

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;

public List<String> listDataTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
public HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

List<String> Project = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> Architecture = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> Task = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> Client = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> Master = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> User = new ArrayList<String>();

public List<Integer> listDataImages;
public int checkGroupPosition;
public int checkChildPositin;
public int projectPosition;
public int architectPosition;
public int clientPosition;
public int taskPosition;
public int masterPosition;
public int userPosition;

int requestcode = 0 ;
String userName;
String userRole;
String userPassword;
public String rolesResponseResult;
public String userRoleWebMethod = "GetAllUserRole";
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
    HashMap<String, String> userRole = sessionManager.getUserDetails();
    userName = userRole.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);
    userPassword = userRole.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERPASSWORD);

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(BaseActivity.this, "", "Getting details  please wait...");
    FetchRolesAsyncTask task = new FetchRolesAsyncTask();
    task.execute();

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.drawer, null);
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) drawer.findViewById(R.id.contentFrame);
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) drawer.findViewById(R.id.drawerListview);
    prepareDefaultData();
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataTitle, listDataChild,drawer, listDataImages);
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            checkGroupPosition = groupPosition;
            checkChildPositin = childPosition;
            ClickChildItems();
            return true;
        }
    });

    drawer.setClickable(true);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) drawer.findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
          setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
          getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }
    };
    drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
    super.setContentView(drawer);
}

private void prepareDefaultData() {
    listDataTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataTitle.add("Home");

    /*// Adding child data
    List<String> homePage = new ArrayList<String>();
    homePage.add("Home");*/

    //listDataChild.put(listDataTitle.get(0), homePage);
}

private void ClickChildItems() {
    final String selected = (String) listAdapter.getChild(checkGroupPosition, checkChildPositin);

    if(selected.equals("Home")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this,Home.class);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("Add Project")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Intent addProjectIntent = new Intent(this,AddProject.class);
        startActivity(addProjectIntent);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("Edit Project")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Intent updateProjectIntent = new Intent(this,UpdateProject.class);
        startActivity(updateProjectIntent);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("Delete Project")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Intent deleteProjectIntent = new Intent(this,DeleteProject.class);
        startActivity(deleteProjectIntent);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("Add SubStage")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Intent addSubStage = new Intent(this,AddSubStage.class);
        startActivity(addSubStage);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("Edit SubStage")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Intent updateSubStage = new Intent(this,UpdateSubStage.class);
        startActivity(updateSubStage);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("Delete SubStage")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Intent deleteSubStage = new Intent(this,DeleteSubStage.class);
        startActivity(deleteSubStage);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("Add Client")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Intent clientIntent = new Intent(this,AddCompany.class);
        clientIntent.putExtra("AddClient","AddClient");
        startActivity(clientIntent);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("Edit Client")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Intent clientIntent = new Intent(this,UpdateCompany.class);
        clientIntent.putExtra("EditClient","EditClient");
        startActivity(clientIntent);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("Delete Client")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Intent clientIntent = new Intent(this,DeleteCompany.class);
        clientIntent.putExtra("DeleteClient","DeleteClient");
        startActivity(clientIntent);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("Add Architect")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        String addValue = "AddArchitec";
        Intent addArchitect = new Intent(this,Architecture.class);
        addArchitect.putExtra("Add",addValue);
        startActivity(addArchitect);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("Edit Architect")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        String editValue = "EditArchitec";
        Intent updateArchitect = new Intent(this,Architecture.class);
        updateArchitect.putExtra("Edit",editValue);
        startActivity(updateArchitect);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("Delete Architect")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        String deleteValue = "DeleteArchitec";
        Intent deleteArchitect = new Intent(this,Architecture.class);
        deleteArchitect.putExtra("Delete",deleteValue);
        startActivity(deleteArchitect);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("Add Task")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Intent addTaskIntent = new Intent(this,AddTask.class);
        startActivity(addTaskIntent);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("Edit Task")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Intent editTaskIntent = new Intent(this,UpdateTask.class);
        startActivity(editTaskIntent);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("Delete Task")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Intent deleteTaskIntent = new Intent(this,DeleteTask.class);
        startActivity(deleteTaskIntent);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("Add User")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Intent addUser = new Intent(this,AddUser.class);
        startActivity(addUser);
    }
    /*else if(selected.equals("Edit User")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
       // Intent updateUser = new Intent(this,UpdateUser.class);
      //  startActivity(updateUser);
    }*/
    else if(selected.equals("State Master")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Intent stateMasterIntent = new Intent(this,StateMaster.class);
        startActivity(stateMasterIntent);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("District Master")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Intent districtMasterIntent = new Intent(this,DistrictMaster.class);
        startActivity(districtMasterIntent);
    }
    else if(selected.equals("Taluka Master")){
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        Intent talukaMasterIntent = new Intent(this,TalukaMaster.class);
        startActivity(talukaMasterIntent);
    }
}

public void setContentView(int layoutId) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(layoutId, null, false);
    drawer.addView(contentView,0);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.option_menu_items, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id ==  R.id.logoutMenu){
        sessionManager.logoutUser();
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void prepareListData() {
    listDataTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataTitle.add("Project");
    listDataTitle.add("Client");
    listDataTitle.add("Architecture");
    listDataTitle.add("Task");
    listDataTitle.add("Master");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> Project = new ArrayList<String>();
    Project.add("Add Project");
    Project.add("Edit Project");
    Project.add("Delete Project");
    Project.add("Add SubStage");
    Project.add("Edit SubStage");
    Project.add("Delete SubStage");

    List<String> Client = new ArrayList<String>();
    Client.add("Add Client");
    Client.add("Edit Client");
    Client.add("Delete Client");

    List<String> Architecture = new ArrayList<String>();
    Architecture.add("Add Architect");
    Architecture.add("Edit Architect");
    Architecture.add("Delete Architect");

    List<String> Task = new ArrayList<String>();
    Task.add("Add Task");
    Task.add("Edit Task");
    Task.add("Delete Task");

    List<String> Master = new ArrayList<String>();
    Master.add("State Master");
    Master.add("District Master");
    Master.add("Taluka Master");

    listDataChild.put(listDataTitle.get(0), Project);
    listDataChild.put(listDataTitle.get(1),Client);
    listDataChild.put(listDataTitle.get(2),Architecture);
    listDataChild.put(listDataTitle.get(3),Task);
    listDataChild.put(listDataTitle.get(4), Master);
}

public class FetchRolesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        rolesResponseResult = GetDataWebService.FetchRoles(userName, userPassword, userRoleWebMethod);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {
        if(rolesResponseResult.equals("Invalid UserName & Password")) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Unable to fetch details");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface alert, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //Do something
                    alert.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
            alert1.show();
        }
        else if(rolesResponseResult.equals("No Network Found")) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Result");
            builder.setMessage("Unable to login. Please try again later.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface alert, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //Do something
                    alert.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
            alert1.show();
        }
        else {
            try {
                JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(rolesResponseResult);
                for (int count = 0; count < jArr.length(); count++) {
                    JSONObject obj = jArr.getJSONObject(count);
                    userRole = obj.getString("menuName");
                    prepareDrawerDetails();
                  //  requestcode = 1;
                  //  sessionManager.createRequestCode(requestcode);
                }
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            catch (JSONException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}

private void prepareDrawerDetails() {

    if(userRole.equals("Project")){
        listDataTitle.add("Project");
        projectPosition = listDataTitle.indexOf("Project");
    }
    else if(userRole.equals("Architect")){
        listDataTitle.add("Architecture");
        architectPosition = listDataTitle.indexOf("Architecture");
    }
    else if(userRole.equals("Client")){
        listDataTitle.add("Client");
        clientPosition = listDataTitle.indexOf("Client");
    }
    else if(userRole.equals("Task")){
        listDataTitle.add("Task");
        taskPosition = listDataTitle.indexOf("Task");
    }
    else if(userRole.equals("User")){
        listDataTitle.add("User");
        userPosition = listDataTitle.indexOf("User");
    }
    else if(userRole.equals("Master")){
        listDataTitle.add("Master");
        masterPosition = listDataTitle.indexOf("Master");
    }

    if(projectPosition != 0){
        if (userRole.equals("Add Project")) {
            Project.add("Add Project");
        }
        else if (userRole.equals("Edit Project")) {
            Project.add("Edit Project");
        }
        else if (userRole.equals("View Project")) {
            Project.add("Delete Project");
        }
        else if (userRole.equals("AddSubStage")) {
            Project.add("Add SubStage");
        }
        else if (userRole.equals("ViewSubStage")) {
            Project.add("Edit SubStage");
            Project.add("Delete SubStage");
        }
        listDataChild.put(listDataTitle.get(projectPosition), Project);
    }

    if(architectPosition != 0){
        if(userRole.equals("Add Architect")){
            Architecture.add("Add Architect");

        }else if(userRole.equals("View Architect")){
            Architecture.add("Edit Architect");
        }
        else if(userRole.equals("View Architect")){
            Architecture.add("Delete Architect");
        }
        listDataChild.put(listDataTitle.get(architectPosition),Architecture);
    }

    if(clientPosition != 0) {
        if (userRole.equals("Add Client")) {
            Client.add("Add Client");
            listDataChild.put(listDataTitle.get(clientPosition), Client);
        } else if (userRole.equals("Edit Client")) {
            Client.add("Edit Client");
            listDataChild.put(listDataTitle.get(clientPosition), Client);
        } else if (userRole.equals("Delete Client")) {
            Client.add("Delete Client");
            listDataChild.put(listDataTitle.get(clientPosition), Client);
        }
    }

    if(userPosition != 0) {
        if (userRole.equals("Add User")) {
            User.add("Add User");
        }
        /*else  if(userRole.equals("Edit User")) {
            User.add("Edit User");
        }*/
        listDataChild.put(listDataTitle.get(userPosition), User);
    }

    if(taskPosition != 0){
        if(userRole.equals("Add Task")){
            Task.add("Add Task");
        }
        else if(userRole.equals("Edit Task")){
            Task.add("Edit Task");
        }
        else if(userRole.equals("View Task")){
            Task.add("Delete Task");
        }
        listDataChild.put(listDataTitle.get(taskPosition),Task);
    }

    if(masterPosition != 0){
        if(userRole.equals("Role Master")){
            Master.add("State Master");
        }
        else if(userRole.equals("District Master")){
            Master.add("District Master");
        }
        else if(userRole.equals("Taluka Master")){
            Master.add("Taluka Master");
        }
        listDataChild.put(listDataTitle.get(masterPosition),Master);
    }
}
```

}

Here is my adapter class

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<String> listDataHeader; // header titles
private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
private List<Integer> listImageDataHeader; // header titles

DrawerLayout drawer;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataTitle, HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild, DrawerLayout drawer, List<Integer> listDataImages) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listImageDataHeader = listDataImages;
    this.listDataHeader = listDataTitle;
    this.listDataChild = listDataChild;
    this.drawer = drawer;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtChildItem);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    String headerImage = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView parentListHeader = (TextView)       convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtParentListHeader);
    parentListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    parentListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageParentListHeader);

    return convertView;
}
@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can add listen to first group position on `getGroupView` in such way:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    String headerImage = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView parentListHeader = (TextView)       convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtParentListHeader);
    parentListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    parentListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageParentListHeader);
    if(groupPosition==0){
     // first parent 
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
    }else{
    convertView.setOnClickListener(null);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```